# Why is confirm() happening first when the javascript before it changes the element's border color?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to simply delete an HTML element via JavaScript when it is clicked and after the user has provided confirmation.

After the click but before the confirmation, I want the element to be highlighted (have a different border color). However, in the code below, the confirmation is happening before the border color changes.

css:

```
.test-box {
            border: 2px solid black;
            height: 200px;
            width: 200px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const testBox = document.createElement('div')
            testBox.className = "test-box"
            document.body.append(testBox)
            // Remove testBox when clicked
            testBox.addEventListener('click', () => {
                // Highlight testBox to be deleted
                testBox.style.border = "2px solid yellow"
                // Confirm deletion
                const confirmation = confirm("Delete testBox?")
                if (confirmation) {
                    testBox.remove()
                } else {
                    // Remove highlight
                    testBox.style.border = "2px solid black"
                }
            })
        })
```

The only way I can get it to work as desired is by adding a 1ms timeout to the confirmation, like this:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const testBox = document.createElement('div')
            testBox.className = "test-box"
            document.body.append(testBox)
            // Remove testBox when clicked
            testBox.addEventListener('click', () => {
                // Highlight testBox to be deleted
                testBox.style.border = "2px solid yellow"
                // Delay confirmation so that highlight will happen before confirmation
                setTimeout(() => {
                    // Confirm deletion
                    const confirmation = confirm("Delete testBox?")
                    if (confirmation) {
                        testBox.remove()
                    } else {
                        // Remove highlight
                        testBox.style.border = "2px solid black"
                    }
                }, 1)
            })
        })
```

Is this the best way around this? I want to understand what is happening.

Comment: DOM changes aren't rendered until the function returns to the main event loop.

Comment: Event loop explained: https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0?t=1199

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updates to the DOM are not immediate and do take some time to complete. In this case, your update is happening within the 1ms your `setTimeout()` function waits before firing off the call to `confirm()`. That's why delaying that function call is working. Without the `setTimeout` the Javascript thread calls `confirm` before your DOM finishes its update. [This](https://macarthur.me/posts/when-dom-updates-appear-to-be-asynchronous) article does a good job explaining what is happening and what you can do to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

`confirm`, `alert` and `input` prevent the JavaScript engine from processing the browser's event queue which would include a paint job.

One way to allow a paint cycle to be executed is to use `requestAnimationFrame` : that will execute the given callback right *before* the paint job, and if you there call `requestAnimationFrame` again, that one will call its callback *after* that paint job, just before the next one. You can use this behaviour to resolve a promise after the next paint cycle. Define the event handler as `async` and await that promise:

```js
const paintCycle = () => new Promise(resolve =>
    requestAnimationFrame(() => requestAnimationFrame(resolve))
);

const testBox = document.createElement('div')
testBox.className = "test-box"
document.body.append(testBox)
// Remove testBox when clicked
testBox.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    // Highlight testBox to be deleted
    testBox.style.border = "2px solid yellow"
    await paintCycle();
    // Confirm deletion
    const confirmation = confirm("Delete testBox?")
    if (confirmation) {
        testBox.remove()
    } else {
        // Remove highlight
        testBox.style.border = "2px solid black"
    }
})
```

```css
.test-box:after {
    content: "click me"
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because:

- JavaScript is single-threaded.
- Updates to the UI won't occur until the blocking operations are complete.
- `confirm()` is a blocking operation.

If you want to use `confirm()` then the approach you've come up with is a reasonable workaround for the UX you're trying to achieve.  A more modern and clean approach would be to not use `confirm()` (or `alert()` or `prompt()`) at all and build a modal confirmation dialog into the page.  (Or use a [3rd party one](https://sweetalert.js.org/), of which there are many.)